# Should Prism RequestNavigate work with no UI?

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a Prism 4.0 enabled WPF application that uses RequestNavigate extensively, and it is working well.  I have a scenario where I would like to render part of my UI to an image and store it for later use from a Windows service.  I already know how to use RenderTargetBitmap to generate the image, but whenever my code tries to call RequestNavigate, nothing happens.  I am calling the bootstrapper, so I would expect that all of the types are loaded, but it just is not working.  Can anyone tell me if this should even be possible?  Is there anything inherent to RequestNavigate that prevents it from working when there is no UI present?

Individual steps:
First, I call Run on my MefBootstrapper.  This loads up all of the assemblies into the AggregateCatalog.

Then, I use MEF CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue to create a WPF UserControl that has a single ContentControl that is assigned a RegionManager.RegionName.  This always creates the initial UserControl just fine.

Finally, I call MefRegionManager.RequestNavigate with the region name on my UserControl and the path to another UserControl that I want it to load.  This fails to load the UserControl that I am attempting to navigate to.

If these are the only steps that I follow, then the final UserControl fails to load whether I am running from a Windows Service or from within my WPF application.  However, if I call SetRegionManager to explicitely add the region from my host UserControl before calling RequestNavigate, then the last UserControl will load properly, as long as the code is run from within the WPF application.  If this same code is run from my Windows service, then it still does not load.

Comment: There is not enough detail in your question.  What do you mean you are calling the bootstrapper?  You are in a WPF app, but with no UI?  When you call RequestNavigate what object are you calling it off of (Region, ReginManager, etc.)?  What are you navigating to in your RequestNavigate method call?  Please provide more detail, and code snippets to help paint the picture more clearly.  Are you trying to navigate to a dynamic image?

Answer (score 0):

RequestNavigate is exactly that, a request to navigate to a loaded (but inactive) region. It won't do any loading itself. You need to separately manage the loading of views (including views within views).

If your nested user control is only over loaded within the parent, and you don't need to manage it at runtime, then you can use *ViewDiscovery*. You register all the views in advance, and then when the region is created, it looks for (and loads) all the nested views.  If you need to manage the views at runtime, switch them in and out, etc, then you can use *ViewInjection*.

For *ViewDiscovery*, in the *Initialize* method of the *ModuleInit* class in your module, insert the following line:

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionNameOfYourNestedControl",
  () => this.container.Resolve<NestedUserControl>());
```

Then when your region is loaded, the *NestedUserControl* will automatically be loaded into your ContentControl (region).

For more detail on ViewDiscovery, ViewInjection and UI composition, [have a read of the prism documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921174(v=pandp.40).aspx)